# Optimize SearchBarController iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I am creating a custom Music Player and I access Music Library using the Predicate given in Apple Documentation.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/UsingTheiPodLibrary/UsingTheiPodLibrary.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765-CH101-SW1

But if I have to search a Library having 10000 songs and more, I find a lag in showing the results in table view. Is there any way that I could fetch the songs and display it in a table view quickly as the Native Music Picker Search Works???

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are fetching all the records form core data in one call. You need to only fetch the data that needs to be displayed on the screen and when the user scrolls down to fetch some more data. You can do this by using the `NSFetchedResultsController` 
[Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller) is a great tutorial

Comment: Johan , how can we access Music Libraries Core Data Model, Apple recommends to query and fetch right (using MPMediaQuery) ???